# MGTwitterEngine Showing Friend Updates

Tags: iphone

I'm using MGTwitterEngine for an iPhone app. I've managed to get it to send updates but can not for the life of me get it to show the user's friends timeline. (i'm a newb programmer) I was hoping someone could post the code to do so. I can do the formating and link the interface builder to the data source. just need to know how to call it from my main View Controller file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[_engine getFollowedTimelineFor:user sinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:10]`

this will return you a request identifier
you also need to implement a

`- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier`

to pick up the results and marry them with your request. These you would probably display in a UITableView

Comment: Thanks was starting to lose hope that my question would be answered. i greatly appreciate it.

Comment: ok so i implemented
[_engine getFollowedTimelineFor:user sinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:10]
but i'm getting the error: "user" undeclared. I've also implemented the "statusesReceived" method to no avail. could you be a little more specific. thanks again.

Comment: user is a string representing the user you are attempting to retrieve status for - their twitter id. - for mine use @"andiih" instead of user

Once that is working, but a breakpoint in statusesReceived (you may need to add a line of code to set the breakpoint on ????) and then in debugger do "po statuses" to see what you get back.  Then you will need to parse the array

Answer (score 0):

just keep this method in viewdidload or viewDidAppear and run it

[_engine getRecentlyUpdatedFriendsFor:nil startingAtPage:0];//Following
[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES]; //followers

you find info on console,